# Pretrained CNN (MobileNet V2) output shape

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I m new to CNN. I m using a pretrained model for my project.
I use the link as reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

when i type: "base_model summary"i see the output shape of last layer as (None,5,5,1280)
so i expect (1,5,5,1280) output shape when my input dimensions are (160,160,3).
But when i check i see that output dimensions are like (32,5,5,1280)
when input is (160,160,3)
I could not understand where that 32 comes from and why it is not included in last layer output shape.
Can anyone help me with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the similar experiment to you that is aimed at applying mobileNetV2 or V3 to being the backend feature extractor. Even though I did not go through the sample code on the colab, I believe that the (32, 5, 5, 1280) is extactly the shape of batched tensors. The 32 is the batch size of the output tensors, i.e feature vectors. Moreover, you probably need to flatten them before fed into a ml classifier.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32467458)